# Bevel tool creating intersecting faces

Tags: modeling

I am trying to use the Bevel tool to make my cinder block have some slightly rounded edges. When I select the edges or verts and use the tool it makes a weird explosion. Any ideas?

[image: bevel]

Comment: This is cause by the new beveled faces overlapping. Check your normals, and i wouldn't have done that from the corners. You may need to subdivide the outer edges to get it more even.

Comment: Poor topology (like that generated from boolean modifiers) generally doesn't play well with bevels. Is it possible you could upload your .blend for us to play around with? Perhaps we can come up with a suitable solution.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33486

Here it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Would be nice to have rounded edges because my object mapped looks too sharp!
![render][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/9QpMFmK.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I would do is delete all the faces on the top along with those nasty triangles and poles... tris and ngons do not subdivide well with bevels.

Try to keep your geometry with quads.

[image]

Once you delete the offending faces, select the edge loops you want to bevel, and on the top view extrude and scale. The idea is to create a new set of edges and faces that follow the topology using quads.

[image]

Those edges will bevel nicely now...

[image]

If you need to bevel the outer edge loops do the same.

[image]

[image]

After that then just fill the gaps with the best topology you can come up with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I love that I can learn using the internet and having helpful people like you support me! Learning new stuff every day. Thanks @cegaton

Comment: I don't understand how you did the bevel part though. I'm here with the extruded scale after deleting the bad faces... but when I use the bevel tool it doesn't do the same thing as you

Comment: Select the edge loop and press Ctrl B.

Comment: How did you get the clean edges on the outside of the cinder block? Mine overlap and go towards the center but yours look even and localized. http://i.imgur.com/TImwy0s.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens when you are trying to bevel 5 or more-edged vertices - the bevel operator does not handle them well.

The solution is to **use n-gons**, and if you want - to triangulate that n-gon back after the bevel.