# Why can't I use the bevel equally on all my loopcuts? Double edge problems

Tags: edit-mode, edges, bevel

I found some answers in this question already posed, but without finding the solution.
([Bevel tool creating intersecting faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21287/bevel-tool-creating-intersecting-faces))

I knocked down the wall several times rebuilding it in different ways and then cutting it again with the loopcuts, but each time I was presented with a different error that I will try to point out through multiple screenshots and also uploading the file, which had already been subjected to a another question.

**1)**. So, what I have to create NOW is a wall that includes cavities along all the cuts (loopcuts), the same ones that I managed to create in the central entrance doors. see fig. 1.
while in fig. 2 I show you how the wall texture should be.

[image] **(fig.1)**

[image] **(fig.2)**

I would like to create them manually instead of attaching a texture to you, what do you recommend?

**2)**. Alternatively I thought I could create them by directly extruding a portion of the cut face, but this would involve further cuts to my only surface, which already seems not to work correctly. (besides, there are also some oblique cuts to be made).
This is what I would like to do: in figure x, you can see the exact blunt edge, where some loops work correctly, while others don't. fig.y
furthermore in figure y, you can see how in transparent mode some walls are visible and others not.

[image] **(fig.x)**
[image] **(fig.y)**

**3)**. I noticed that there are several double edges and vertices which sometimes prevent me from loopcuts or change the direction of the bevel. How can I remove all duplicates? (fig. 3 and 4)
In the vertices I tried using the merge - by distance, it signals me a lot of vertices and applying it several times gets to 0, but I'm not sure if it has removed them. What about the edges instead? how do i locate them, know where the duplicates are and remove them? Do I have to do it manually or is there a shortcut?
[image] (**fig.3)**
[image] **(fig.4)**

ps. I wanted to upload the file but now it weighs 76mb how can I do? is already compressed.I put this google drive link to download the file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/182UTa6t7IOB7K0iE7T3Nr6QqnF-4NoOk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, I think there are a lot of questions and it's a bit confusing, maybe choose one question at a time and make it very clear and simple? Also, it looks like, like for many buildings, yours is made of the repetition of the exact same pattern, so maybe try to build only one pattern, make sure that everything's ok, and repeat it with an Array modifier? Otherwise it will be hell. Once you're glad you can apply the Array, if necessary...

Comment: It seemed useless to ask 3 separate questions, as they concern only one project. i have ordered all in points and steps, you should understand the problems enough.
I mean it's all a big big problem, i don't know what i should solve first. @moonboots

Comment: Yes the scheme is identical, in fact for the windows I used an array, but the problem is the wall that I divided by loopcut which has all these problems: double edges, wrong normals, and the bevel does not work correctly on the loops. @moonboots

Comment: I removed the question of the '' normals '' I turned them manually leaving the outside in blue and the back as the inside in red. Now it should be easier since there is only one problem, that is to recreate that texture if it is recommended through the loopcuts and the bevel as shown in the figure, or alternatively another method to not do it manually.

Comment: As for your previous question. If I rephrase: this should be constructed like a Lego. Many parts are similar. Model them once and make an assembly duplicating them... but it seems you want to do it another way...

Comment: @lemon, yes that's why I was talking about array, the same pattern is repeated on the horizontal axis

Comment: But the model is still one piece...

Comment: yes, apply the Array once you're good

Comment: Yes, I wanted to try to do the whole facade in a maximum of two steps, use the bevel and extrude inwards to generate the recess. but it seems to be more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what's the method you're using, what are the problems you're encounting, etc, but if I had to do this kind of walls, I would make only one segment that I would repeat with the *Array* modifier to make things easier, and for the bricks, if you want to keep the whole thing as one unique object, you could:

- Cut some orthogonal lines, bevel them:

[image]

- Extrude them and bevel the extrusion (for example with a Bevel modifier with *Limit Method > Angle*):

[image]

[image]

If you think that there's a problem with this kind of method, please tell me?

Comment: it is exactly the method I am using, but as you can see from the screenshots many loopcuts do not respond well to the bevel modifier, and do not allow me to perform a correct bevel on all the loopcuts at the same time, nor evenly.
I followed this method as you can see in figure 1 in the example of the pilasters.
In my opinion, the problems that I think may affect this process include double edges. then I don't know. i have linked my file if u want.

Comment: I tried to knock down the wall and make a new one and loop it but I haven't solved it.

Comment: there are many ways why a bevel can fail, so it's hard to sum them up, but to simplify your work, maybe first make the window a different object so that it doesn't interfere with your work on the brick wall. Plus in general, if an object is separated in real life, it's better to do a separate mesh (or object) in 3D. You could even make one separate mesh per brick.

Comment: What I actually did is (after an infinite series of tests and manual corrections), extrude edge by edge to recreate the faces of the wall, to allow the loop to be generated because in some phases of the wall creation I couldn't even to divide it with the loopcuts. I wanted to avoid having to do everything manually as I believe there are other methods.